# NSURLConnection response returns 500 Status Code

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

I am trying to connect to a local node.js server setup and authenticate the user. I keep getting the 500 status code and can't figure out what I am missing. 
I have tried hitting the server with these credentials from a web browser, and it works as expected.

Note: I do understand I have to use the NSURLSession instead of NSURLConnection, but for now, I need to get this to work.

Here is my code,

```
func signInUserWithDetails(userName:String,userPassword:String,serverURL:NSURL) {
    let credDic :[String:String]=["user[name]":userName,
                                   "user[password]":userPassword ]
    self.httpMethod="PUT"
    self.httpPath="/account"
    self.expectedStatusCode=201

    self.actualStatusCode=NSNotFound
    self.requestUniqueIdentifier = NSUUID().UUIDString

    let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(URL: serverURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
    urlComponents.path = httpPath
    let formedURL = urlComponents.URL!
    var requestOrg = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: formedURL)

    requestOrg.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    requestOrg.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    requestOrg.HTTPMethod=self.httpMethod!

    print(requestOrg.allHTTPHeaderFields) // Output 1

    do{
        let theJSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(credDic,options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        let theJSONText = NSString(data: theJSONData,encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)

        requestOrg.HTTPBody = theJSONData;

        let tempD=try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(requestOrg.HTTPBody!, options: []) as? [String:String]
        print("\(tempD)")  //Output 2

    }catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

   connection = NSURLConnection(request: requestOrg, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
}
```

And I am just printing out the response with this,

```
func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse) {
    print("----------------------didReceiveResponse")
    self.response=response
    print("Response Received:"+"\(self.response)")
    let urlResponse:NSHTTPURLResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
    let responseCode=urlResponse.statusCode
    self.actualStatusCode=responseCode
}
```

And the result I get is

```
Optional(["Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"])
Optional(["user[password]": "R", "user[name]": "R"])
----------------------didReceiveResponse
Response Received:Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7faba269d440> { URL:   http://localhost:3000/account } { status code: 500, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 1464;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Sat, 26 Dec 2015 08:34:45 GMT";
"X-Powered-By" = Express;
} })
```

And the *didReceiveData* throws this error

```
{"error":{"message":"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined","stack":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined\n    at Object.exports.signIn [as handle] ( .......
```

Comment: Looks like server expects to receive `"name"` property, probably instead of `"user[name]"`.

Comment: @kelin , I tried changing it and no, it doesn't make a difference! Also, I have the same dictionary being sent in an obj-c version of this code and it works fine! (a more modularized version though)

Comment: @`pavithramouli`, please can you add that working obj-c version to the question? It can give a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status code 500 means, that the server could not process your data and ran into an internal error. This oftentimes is caused by improperly encoded HTTP messages, where the server was unable to catch all possible errors.

When looking at your code, it becomes immediately apparent:

You are not sending a properly `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded data to the server. This is likely the main cause of your problem. The other cause might be, that it's likely not a `PUT` but a `POST` method which is required to sign-in.

But before explaining how you encode your data properly, I would suggest to find out whether your server accepts JSON as content data (`application/json`). If so, properly encoding the data is much easier: having a JSON object (your variable `credDic`), simply convert it to JSON as UTF-8 in a `NSData` container. Then, get the length in bytes, set headers `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` accordingly.

Comment: I checked that it needed a PUT and not a POST, also, I tried setting the content-type as **'let charset = CFStringConvertEncodingToIANACharSetName(CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        
        requestOrg.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=\(charset)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")'** with the content-length taken from **theJSONData.length** ... And the same result :( 
        '

Comment: I even tried changing it from application/x-www-form-urlencoded to plain application/json .. Didn't work..

Comment: Note: content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` does not have a charset parameter. It will be ignored by the server. Servers should assume UTF-8 - unless your client has a form. You need to check the API, and possibly contact the web service team, how parameters should be set. As mentioned, easiest would be `application/json` with your serialised `credDic` in UTF-8. Note: with `application/json` you can optionally set a charset parameter.

Comment: thanks, you did put me in the right direction. I finally understood what it is the **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** type needed and constructed my httpbody so. And it works as expected!

Comment: I am refining the code now to properly sort the keys as expected in the **credDic** to form the body (any smart ways?). I will then post it here, in case it helps someone later on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but after tried to include **Content-Type** using **application/json**, it was solved.

**Example**: request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Answer (score 0):

The client application gets an HTTP status code of 500 with the message "Internal Server Error" as a response for API calls. The 500 Internal Server error could be caused by an error during the execution of any policy within Edge or by an error on the target/backend server.

The HTTP status code 500 is a generic error response. It means that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. This error is usually returned by the server when no other error code is suitable